# How to fix ImportError in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I install new version of Anaconda (Python 3.6) and now I can not import PyQt.
I reinstalled it three times and add `<>\Anaconda3.6\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin` to `PATH` variable. But it did not help.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: Could not find the specified module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add file `python3.dll` from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-361/) to your anaconda's directory.
In my case i had there only `python36.dll`